When re-parenting a JFrame it also moves when parent Frame moves ! (since Java 16)
I use JNA on windows to re-parent a JFrame inside another OS-native Frame.
I made a SSCCE sample to demonstrate the problem: https://github.com/fmarot/frame-reparent-resize-sscce . In my real-world use case, I'm not in control of the parent frame which is not in Java.
The problem is that since Java 16, when the parent Frame is moved around, the child JFrame also moves around inside the parent Frame ! Up to Java 15 it was not the case.
Any advice whether this behavior is a bug or expected is welcome. Maybe I should open a bug on the OpenJDK ? What Do You Think ?



If you are asking for people's opinions, then I believe such a question is not suitable for SO.

hi, I'm not asking people's opinion but I ask for their knowledge for wether the behavior is a bug or expected since Java16. I think the problem is complex and I did my best to explain it, including a SSCCE.
